# Populate username and password on another domain from my domain?

Tags: security, authentication, same-origin-policy

I have received a request, and I cannot find a secure way to implement it. If you know a secure way to do this, please let me know.

I'm developing www.abcd.com with ASP.NET MVC. The client already has a xyz.abcd.com domain with an authentication system. They want me to create a page on www.abcd.com, where user can enter a username and password, then by hitting the login button, I open a xyz.abcd.com/login page in a new window and populate username and password with what the user has typed in my page.

1. I cannot find a way to do it from server-side.
2. If I want to do it on the client-side, I think it's against "same-origin policy" and also, I'm not sure running both www.abcd.com and xyz.abcd.com on SSL is secure enough to do such a thing.

Could you please let me know, if there is a secure solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the subdomain application (on xyz.abcd.com) should have explicit support for this to be possible, like for example populating its fields from request parameters or maybe a cookie (though I would rather not do that, especially not in case of the password).

If the subdomain application does not support this, I think you can't populate its fields, not even from abcd.com, let alone from another domain.

Please note that it would be a vulnerability (and against the best practice of course) to auto-populate the password field, which should even be set autocomplete="off" to prevent even the browser itself from filling it in.

Without knowing the context to these applications, I suspect you need some kind of a single sign-on to achieve your real goal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I agree with you, and for any cross-domain authentication, OAuth 2 already exists. I should just convince the client that it's not a good solution. Thanks again.